# Letter Combination Plot

Tags: plotting, subset

How do I make a plot that displays the total number of letter combinations of n letters (from n=1 to 26)?

I've been trying with subset but can't get the syntax right.

Comment: Have you seen [`Binomial`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Binomial.html) ?

Comment: If all n  letters are different, the number is !n. If you have n1, n2 ,..  identical characters, the number is: n!/(n1! n2! ..)